# How to navigate the user to required view controller on tap of deep link for fresh installation of app with firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, deep-linking

I want to navigate the user to specific view controller on click of deep linking

If a user already installed the app I am able do by using below method in app delegate

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                 restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool
```

But how to navigate the user to desired ViewController for first time installation of app

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use UserDefaults...

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], 
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let alreadyInitialized = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "AlreadyInitialized")
    if !alreadyInitialized {
        UserDefaults.set(true, forKey: "AlreadyInitialized")

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstTimeViewController") as FirstTimeViewController
        let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

        navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: I am done with navigation code but my question is how to get the deep link URL on first time installation ?